# How to break a line (add a newline) in read -p in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, newline

How could I break a line using `\n` in `read -p`?

For example

```
read -p "Please Enter the percent [30 between 100]\n The value is  Default = 80   :" scale_percent
```

I want `\n` to break a line but it doesn't work.

In `echo` I use `-e` and it breaks a line.

So I tried

```
read -ep
```

to break the line but it didn't break the line. How can I do that?

And could you also please give me a good manual for `read -p` on the  Internet because I couldn't find a nice one without a confusing description.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
read -p $'Please Enter the percent [30 between 100]\x0a The value is  Default = 80   :' scale_percent
```

we use above syntax to insert hex values, we insert `\x0a` which is the hexadecimal value of the newline character (**LF**). You can use same syntax above with `echo` to produce new lines, eg:

```
echo $'One line\x0asecond line'
```

This is a feature of **BASH 2**, it is documented [**here**](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting), the `$''` is used to translate all escape sequences inside it for its ascii transcription. So we could obtain the same result of example above, this way:

```
echo $'One line\nsecond line'
```

Comment: Awesome thank you, where do you learn these things ? is there any book or just experience ?

Comment: I learned by experience, specifically http://stackoverflow.com/a/4745850/352672  Also there are docs, will update my answer with that.

Comment: @MedyaGh: You can also find documentation when you run  `man bash` and search for chapter heading `QUOTING`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following to include variables in the prompt:

```
some_var='first line'
read -p "$some_var"$'\n'"second line " user_input
echo $user_input
```

(I wanted to make this a comment to Nelson's answer, but I could not have newlines for code readability.)

Comment: thank you!!! Along with the newlines, I needed a way to insert variables into the prompt, and none of the other solutions mentioned this. Very much appreciated!!!